# Why it is not until the end menu? JQuery layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this page:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/)

As you can see in the picture below, my menu is not until the end ... there is a distance of about 17px.
If you resize the window only look great menu `document.ready ()` is the problem.

**CODE JS:**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var windowheight = $(window).outerHeight();
    var meniu= $('.navbar-fixed-top').outerHeight();
    console.log('inaltime ecran:',windowheight);
    console.log('inaltime meniu:',meniu);
    $('#main-content').css('height', 100+'vh');
    $('#main-content').css('height', $('#main-content').outerHeight() - 50);
    var windowsize = $(window).outerWidth();
    console.log('screen width:',windowsize);
    var stanga= jQuery('#secondary').outerWidth();
    console.log('left width:',stanga);
    var dreapta= jQuery('.right').outerWidth();
    console.log('width right:',dreapta);
    var contentwh=windowsize-stanga-dreapta;
    console.log('laatime content:',contentwh);
    $('#main-content').css('width',contentwh+20);
    var content= jQuery('#main-content').outerWidth();
    $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('width',contentwh+5);



          $(window).on('resize',function(){
          $('#main-content').css('height', 100+'vh');
          $('#main-content').css('height', $('#main-content').outerHeight() - 50);
          var windowsize = $(window).outerWidth();   
          var stanga= jQuery('#secondary').outerWidth();
          var dreapta= jQuery('.right').outerWidth();
          var contentwh=windowsize-stanga-dreapta;
          $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('width',contentwh+5);
          console.log('laatime content rezise:',contentwh);
    $('#main-content').css('width',contentwh+20);

    });
    });
```

http://i57.tinypic.com/2hz1d9u.jpg

Does anyone know what is the problem and what's wrong calculations?
Can you help me please fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use JQuery for this ? CSS can do this faster and without any problem.

Comment: because I want to learn and jQuery